DV01 of Cross Currency Swap
I'm trying to calculate DV01 of USD - KRW cross currency swap.
Curve building process for swap was as following:

Generate USD discount curve which makes PV of market observable USD IRS become zero (Curve #490 in Bloomberg ICVS)
Generate KRW discount curve which makes PV of market observable USD - KRW CRS become zero (Curve #58 in Bloomberg ICVS)

I understand that DV01 is calculated by shifting the market rate, and obtained proper values for single currency IRS. My question is:

Which rates should be shifted in cross currency swap? (Either the rates used for building USD discount curve or rates used for building KRW discount curve?)
What if market instruments used for building curve is not quoted by interest rates, but FX rate? Should I convert this FX rate to equivalent interest rate and shift it?


you need 3 curves to correctly price XCSs, not 2.

What is the third curve? Would you explain in detatil?

3rd curve in your case would be something to project your KRW payment amounts / forward rates. In a typical Xccy swap you would exchange SOFR against e.g. KOFR. SOFR payments and disc factors you already have, as well as disc curve for the KRW payments -- but you lack the forecasts of the latter.

Thanks for all your comments!
